# How to set underline to space with Java POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I try to set underline with `XWPFRun.setUnderline` but it doesn't work when I try to use space string.
The code like this:

```java
public static void setFilingParagraph(XWPFDocument doc, String beforeStr,String afterStr) {
    XWPFParagraph p = doc.createParagraph();
    p.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);
    p.setSpacingBeforeLines(50);
    p.setSpacingAfterLines(50);
    XWPFRun r = p.createRun();
    r.setBold(false);
    r.setText(beforeStr);
    r.setColor("000000");
    r.setFontSize(14);
    if (afterStr != null) {
        XWPFRun run = p.createRun();
        run.setText(afterStr);
        run.setColor("000000");
        run.setUnderline(UnderlinePatterns.SINGLE);
        run.setFontSize(14);
    }
}
```

When `afterStr` is (for example) `"             "` then `run.setUnderline(UnderlinePatterns.SINGLE);` does not work.
How to deal this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is how Microsoft Word handles underlining of spaces. It underlines simple spaces between words. But it not underlines simple spaces which are not followed by any character. Nevertheless it underlines non breaking spaces.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

public class CreateWordUnderlined {
    
 public static void setFilingParagraph(XWPFDocument doc, String beforeStr, String afterStr) {
  XWPFParagraph p = doc.createParagraph();
  p.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);
  p.setSpacingBeforeLines(50);
  p.setSpacingAfterLines(50);
  XWPFRun r = p.createRun();
  r.setBold(false);
  r.setText(beforeStr);
  r.setColor("000000");
  r.setFontSize(14);
  if (afterStr != null) {
   XWPFRun run = p.createRun();
   run.setText(afterStr);
   run.setColor("000000");
   run.setUnderline(UnderlinePatterns.SINGLE);
   run.setFontSize(14);
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  try ( FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./CreateWordUnderlined.docx");  
        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(); ) {
            
   String beforeStr = "A sample text ";
   String afterStr = "             "; // only simple spaces will not be underlined
   setFilingParagraph(doc, beforeStr, afterStr);
   afterStr = "             ."; // spaces folowed by a character will be underlined
   setFilingParagraph(doc, beforeStr, afterStr);
   afterStr = "            \u00A0"; // spaces folowed by a non breaking space will be underlined
   setFilingParagraph(doc, beforeStr, afterStr);
   afterStr = "\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0"; // non breaking spaces will be underlined
   setFilingParagraph(doc, beforeStr, afterStr);

   doc.write(out);
  }
 }
}
```

Result:

[image]